# primeng datatable - Cannot read property 'index' of undefined

Tags: angular, primeng, angular5, primeng-datatable

i'm trying to use primeng dataTable with the following properties:
`editable='true' rowGroupMode="rowspan`"

but it seems like these two properties can't work together.
When trying to edit a table grouped cell I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (datatable.d.ts.TableBody.html:23)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14689)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13836)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

I've tried it with angular 4 and angular 5 with no success.

This is my HTML code:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="newData" [editable]="true" editMode="row" editingRow="true" [rows]="15" rowGroupMode="rowspan" sortField="resourceGroup">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols">
                <p-column [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [editable]="col.editable"></p-column>
            </ng-container>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: can you show me the whole code line starting from there div tags

Answer (score 0):

use [editable]="true" on table as well as on column 
like

```
<p-dataTable [value]="yourArray" [editable]="true">
 <p-column field="yourField" header="yourHeader" [editable]="true"></p-column>
```

Comment: I've added my html code. As you can see I already have [editable]='true' in my code but still getting error in the console on every key stroke when trying to edit a grouped cell.